# How to place div bottom of window/Navbar HTML - materializecss

Tags: html, css, position, materialize, sidebar

I am trying to place a div container at bottom of my NavBar that I created using materializecss but no matter what I try it does stick to the bottom. It either disappears from NavBar or goes to the top.

I tried

```
#bottomDiv{
    float: bottom;
}
#bottomDiv{
    position: relative; // absolute and fixed
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I searched online and every resource i come across it suggest to use `bottom: 0` but it doesnt seem to work.

I tried creating a JSfiddle to show my code but I couldn't manage to get it work because it wouldn't import the materlizecss libraries - http://jsfiddle.net/jy6Lh7ct/8/

[image]

Any help would be nice, i have been searching and trying different possibilities but have had no luck - this is the link to the website i am following - https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html

Comment: Not sure I understand, but you could take it out of the `<li>` and place it outside of the `<ul>` and/or maybe set margin-top for the div from the element above it.  Also, I'm not sure if `float: bottom;` is proper css.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, i am fairly new to web development so been trying and learning stuff tutorials I watch - I think i saw float: bottom; being used someway to achieve what I want but it doesnt seem to work in my case. I can play around with your suggestion of <li> our from <ul? and see how that goes but it might mess up the navbar.

Comment: I tried taking it out but that doesn't seem to help as it moves outside from the navbar completely

Comment: maybe try `margin-top: 90%`, for example on bottomdiv? See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jy6Lh7ct/12/ . Tough to say without including the other CSS.

Comment: No luck, the code i have so far is taken from this URL - https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html I pasted the code in jsfiddle but it doesn't seem to grab the require libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure it sticks to the bottom with this

```
#bottomDiv{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jy6Lh7ct/17/)

Comment: Hi it makes the bottomDiv completely vanish from the page. I think this is maybe because the code you provided works on actual page but it doesn't recognize that it is inside a sidebar.

Comment: Ok tried adjusting it on the page https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html. Change the value to `bottom: 70px` or whatever you prefer.